# dict.popitem() in python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

In the last versions of python, the builtin dictionary {} preserves the order, just like the OrderedDict (even if it's not guaranteed to do so).

Does dict.popitem() always return the last key-value pair from the dictionary, or a random one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. From the [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.popitem) (3.7):

> **popitem()**
>
> Remove and return a (key, value) pair from the dictionary. **Pairs are returned in LIFO order.**

The same [also applies](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict.popitem) to `collections.OrderedDict` before Python 3.7.

However, do note that `dict.popitem` (the non-ordered version) has no guarantee in Python 3.6 or older versions.

Answer (score 3):

You mention python 3.5 (which is not the latest version), for which the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dict.popitem) say:

> **popitem()**
>     Remove and return an **arbitrary** (key, value) pair from the dictionary.

where arbitrary means implementation dependent (possibly based on [PYTHONHASHSEED](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED)), but not necessarily random or LIFO.

Since the latest python 3.7 however, like @iBug mentions, it's [LIFO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.popitem).